# how to use react-router? it shows warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, reactjs-flux, react-router

I use the following dependencies with CommonJS.
I am trying to render App and Home together.
Home component should only render when `DefaultRoute`'s path is  `path="/"` or `path="home"`.
but for some reasons, I got lots of warnings.
What am I missing?
I've spent days by followings a bunch of examples and tutorials..
Any hint or solution would be very appreciated.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "browserify": "~> 10.2.4",
  "browserify-incremental": "^3.0.1",
  "coffeeify": "~> 0.6",
  "events": "^1.0.2",
  "flux": "^2.0.3",
  "i18next-client": "^1.10.2",
  "object-assign": "^3.0.0",
  "react": "^0.13.3",
  "react-router": "^0.13.3",
  "reactify": "^1.1.1"
}
```

**app.js**

```
var Main = require("./main.js");
var Router = require("react-router");
var Route = Router.Route;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
var Home = require("./components/home.js.jsx");

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      signedIn: null,
      currentUser: null
    };
  },
  componentWillMount: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/is_signed_in",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json"
    }).success(function(response){
      this.setSignedIn(response);
    }.bind(this));
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    Main();
  },
  setSignedIn: function(response){
    this.setState({ signedIn: response.signed_in, currentUser: $.parseJSON(response.current_user) });
    console.log(Home);
  },
  render: function(){
    // <RouteHandler signedIn={this.state.signedIn} />
    return (<RouteHandler />);
  }
});

// React.render(<App />, document.body);

var routes = (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Home} />
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function(Handler){
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

**Logs**

```
Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `routeDepth` was not specified in `RouteHandler`. Check the render method of `App`.
Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `router` was not specified in `RouteHandler`. Check the render method of `App`.
Warning: owner-based and parent-based contexts differ (values: `undefined` vs `1`) for key (routeDepth) while mounting RouteHandler (see: http://fb.me/react-context-by-parent)
Warning: owner-based and parent-based contexts differ (values: `undefined` vs `function (props, context) {
      // This constructor is overridden by mocks. The argument is used
      // by mocks to assert on what gets mounted.

      if ("production" !== "development") {
        ("production" !== "development" ? warning(
          this instanceof Constructor,
          'Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or ' +
          'JSX instead. See: https://fb.me/react-legacyfactory'
        ) : null);
      }

      // Wire up auto-binding
      if (this.__reactAutoBindMap) {
        bindAutoBindMethods(this);
      }

      this.props = props;
      this.context = context;
      this.state = null;

      // ReactClasses doesn't have constructors. Instead, they use the
      // getInitialState and componentWillMount methods for initialization.

      var initialState = this.getInitialState ? this.getInitialState() : null;
      if ("production" !== "development") {
        // We allow auto-mocks to proceed as if they're returning null.
        if (typeof initialState === 'undefined' &&
            this.getInitialState._isMockFunction) {
          // This is probably bad practice. Consider warning here and
          // deprecating this convenience.
          initialState = null;
        }
      }
      ("production" !== "development" ? invariant(
        typeof initialState === 'object' && !Array.isArray(initialState),
        '%s.getInitialState(): must return an object or null',
        Constructor.displayName || 'ReactCompositeComponent'
      ) : invariant(typeof initialState === 'object' && !Array.isArray(initialState)));

      this.state = initialState;
    }`) for key (router) while mounting RouteHandler (see: http://fb.me/react-context-by-parent)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRouteAtDepth' of undefined
Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `routeDepth` was not specified in `RouteHandler`. Check the render method of `App`.
Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `router` was not specified in `RouteHandler`. Check the render method of `App`.
Warning: owner-based and parent-based contexts differ (values: `undefined` vs `1`) for key (routeDepth) while mounting RouteHandler (see: http://fb.me/react-context-by-parent)
Warning: owner-based and parent-based contexts differ (values: `undefined` vs `function (props, context) {
      // This constructor is overridden by mocks. The argument is used
      // by mocks to assert on what gets mounted.

      if ("production" !== "development") {
        ("production" !== "development" ? warning(
          this instanceof Constructor,
          'Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or ' +
          'JSX instead. See: https://fb.me/react-legacyfactory'
        ) : null);
      }

      // Wire up auto-binding
      if (this.__reactAutoBindMap) {
        bindAutoBindMethods(this);
      }

      this.props = props;
      this.context = context;
      this.state = null;

      // ReactClasses doesn't have constructors. Instead, they use the
      // getInitialState and componentWillMount methods for initialization.

      var initialState = this.getInitialState ? this.getInitialState() : null;
      if ("production" !== "development") {
        // We allow auto-mocks to proceed as if they're returning null.
        if (typeof initialState === 'undefined' &&
            this.getInitialState._isMockFunction) {
          // This is probably bad practice. Consider warning here and
          // deprecating this convenience.
          initialState = null;
        }
      }
      ("production" !== "development" ? invariant(
        typeof initialState === 'object' && !Array.isArray(initialState),
        '%s.getInitialState(): must return an object or null',
        Constructor.displayName || 'ReactCompositeComponent'
      ) : invariant(typeof initialState === 'object' && !Array.isArray(initialState)));

      this.state = initialState;
    }`) for key (router) while mounting RouteHandler (see: http://fb.me/react-context-by-parent)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
```

**home.js.jsx**

```
var home = function(){

  var HomeHero = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("homeHero")[0].className = "homeHero container header pure-u-1 u-size1040";
    },
    render: function() {
      return(
        <div className="hero textAlignCenter">
          <h1 className="hero-logo"><a href="/">LOGO</a></h1>
          <h2 className="hero-description">DESCRIPTION.</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  var Home = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
        Home
       </div>
      );
    }
  });

  React.render(<HomeHero />, document.getElementsByClassName("homeHero")[0]);
  React.render(<Home />, document.getElementsByClassName("home")[0]);

};

module.exports = home;
```

---

**Finally Fixed The Problems!** 
I actually use Ruby on Rails framework and `react-rails` gem.
I suppose the react files from the gem is different with original react.
As soon as I replace *react gem* files with *react* installed from npm, everything worked.

damn...it took me several days to figure out.
thank you for all of the answers guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example works error free:

(I also have a gulpfile doing a babelify transform with browserify - putting `react` and `react-router` into a separate file named `vendors.js` - ommitted here)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/vendors.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

**app.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var Home = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
        <h1>Home</h1>
      )
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <RouteHandler />
      </div>
      )
  }
});

var routes = (
  <Route path='/' handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Home} />
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function(Handler){
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

`react-router` handles much of the heavy lifting for you.  If you want to render to a different location, you change that in the render.

```
Router.run(routes, function(Handler){
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('someId'));
});
```

With your added `home` code, if you want to have a router there, you can also do that as well following a similar pattern as above, and add a `<RouteHandler />` to the `home` module.

The [docs](https://rackt.github.io/react-router/) are really helpful - but it's easy to get out of their scope with your complexity.  I've done a few complex route schemes - it can all be done.

**EDIT**
Added a repo to this here - https://github.com/kellyjandrews/react-touter-testing

I went ahead and include all of the node modules - mostly because I was lazy and didn't validate my `package.json`.  Should be able to run `gulp` from the folder, and you will see "Home" in the browser. If you are getting warnings from this - you have something going on that I can't fix from here.

Comment: My react-router and react are ^0.13.3. and React Router 0.13 supports React 0.13 if you read the last comment at https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/638. I have the same errors when I did follow your code..

Comment: Its possible your home module is the problem. Let me get something that is working on my end.

Comment: I added my cleaned home.js.jsx on the question. I think I found the problem. I was already rendering 'home' components inside `home.js.jsx`. but I want to render the component at different parent node, not at `document.body`. is there a workaround to customize `React.render` in `Router.run` for subcomponents?

Comment: You wouldn't need to do that no - it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  I have a working simplified example that you can build from. I'll update shortly.

Comment: Updated - it's a really simple example - but no errors on my console. Start here, and that should answer this question regarding fixing the errors.  Open a new one for other issues you start running into.  Definitely start slow and work your way up.  It's easy to get lost here.

Comment: I am really sorry but the errors on the console still appear although I followed your updated answer.

Comment: You must have something else going on. I'll put this in a repo for you to download and try. But it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are rendering outside the component that has the react-router. see your home component. you should just let `<RouteHandler />` do the rendering to pass the context variables. hope helps

Comment: What do you mean by letting <RouteHandler /> do the rendering? Then you mean I should not use react-router in app.js.jsx?

Comment: i mean in you home. `react.render` should be ommited. only the render function.
    ```export const Home = React.createClass({
       render() { return <div>This is my Home Component</div>}
    });```
then import it into the app.js.jsx

Comment: Nope. That was not a problem. When I removed react-rails gem and used node package react, it worked

Comment: i doubt this would work, because your home renders its own components. if you put react-router tags on it, surely it will fail. like adding `<Link> <RouteHandler>` and such. but good job on fixing :)

Comment: Oh i got what you meant. I did not follow that code. It was just sample code. I had my own production code.